# LEFT JOIN que retorne apenas um registro

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Blz galera? TO tentando aqui fazer uma query funcionar, mas sem sucesso então vo postar aqui.

Tenho duas tabelas ai, tab_usuarios, e tab_enderecos:

tab_usuarios:

| id_usuario | nome | usuario |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Administrador | admin |
| 2 | Novo Usuário | teste |
| 3 | Joao Silva | jao |

tab_enderecos:

| id_endereco | id_usuario | cidade | uf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | cidade | SP |
| 20 | 2 | Lorena | SP |
| 22 | 2 | Lorena | SP |
| 24 | 3 | Campinas | SP |
| 28 | 4 | Lorena | SP |

Eu tenho essa query aqui:

```
Select
    u.id_usuario,
    u.usuario,
    u.nome,
    e.id_endereco,
    e.cidade,
    e.uf
From
    tab_usuarios u Left Join
    tab_enderecos e On u.id_usuario = e.id_usuario
```

que me retorna estes resultados

| id_usuario | usuario | nome | id_endereco | cidade | uf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | admin | Administrador | 2 | cidade | SP |
| 2 | user 2 | Novo Usuário | 22 | Lorena | SP |
| 2 | user 2 | Novo Usuário | 20 | Lorena | SP |
| 3 | jao | Joao Silva | 24 | Campinas | SP |
| 4 | teste | fabio | 28 | Lorena | SP |

A parada é que eu quero que o left join me retorne apenas 1 endereço. Veja que para o usuário user 2, ele retorna 2 endereços, o que é correto, pois ele tem dois endereços cadastrados. Mas, para a view que eu estou criando, eu gostaria que ele retornasse apenas 1 endereço, e no caso seria o que foi cadastrado primeiro, então seria tipo min(id_endereco)

Valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabelas Temp:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tab_usuarios;
CREATE TABLE #tab_usuarios (
    id_usuario INT,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    usuario VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tab_enderecos;
CREATE TABLE #tab_enderecos (
    id_endereco INT,
    id_usuario INT,
    cidade VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    uf VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #tab_usuarios(id_usuario, nome, usuario)
VALUES(1, 'Administrador', 'admin');
INSERT INTO #tab_usuarios(id_usuario, nome, usuario)
VALUES(2, ' Novo Usuário', 'teste');
INSERT INTO #tab_usuarios(id_usuario, nome, usuario)
VALUES(3, 'Joao Silva', 'jao');


SELECT * from #tab_usuarios

INSERT INTO #tab_enderecos(id_endereco, id_usuario, cidade, uf)
VALUES

(2  ,1  ,'cidade',  'SP'),
(20 ,2  ,'Lorena',  'SP'),
(22 ,2  ,'Lorena',  'SP'),
(24 ,3  ,'Campinas','SP'),
(28 ,4  ,'Lorena','SP');

SELECT * from #tab_enderecos
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
Select
    u.id_usuario,
    u.usuario,
    u.nome,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  e.id_usuario  ORDER BY e.id_endereco) as e_cnt,
    e.id_endereco,
    e.cidade,
    e.uf
From
    #tab_usuarios u Left Join
    #tab_enderecos e On u.id_usuario = e.id_usuario  
    ) a 
    WHERE e_cnt =1
```

Comment: deu -1 porque? Testei e sempre traz só um endereço com o minimo id. Isto que eu entendi que voce pediu, pelo menos comenta para a gente porque  voce acha que esta errado.

Comment: fala man, funcionou perfeitamente, muito grato (fui eu que de -1 não, tem algum troll ae)

Comment: cara, agora tem uma outra questão, na verdade, eu tenho uma outra tabela também, tab_contatos, que tem basicamente a mesma estrutura da tab_enderecos, pode ter multiplos contatos do mesmo usuario, e eu tambem queria retornar apenas o primeiro id

teria como eu juntar tudo numa query só?
tentei aqui usando a sua lógica colocar também a tabela contato, porém não funciona (separadas, funcionam bom)

Comment: que coisa estranho.

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tab_contatos;
CREATE TABLE #tab_contatos (
    id_contato INT,
    id_usuario INT,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tab_contatos(id_contato, id_usuario, nome)
VALUES

(2 ,1 ,'Fidalgo'),
(20 ,2 ,'Joao'),
(22 ,2 ,'Maria'),
(24 ,3 ,'Fulano'),
(28 ,4 ,'Lorena');

Comment: SELECT * FROM (
Select
    u.id_usuario,
    u.usuario,
    u.nome,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  e.id_usuario  ORDER BY e.id_endereco) as e_cnt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  c.id_usuario  ORDER BY c.nome) as c_cnt,
    e.id_endereco,
    e.cidade,
    e.uf,
    c.nome as contato
From
    #tab_usuarios u Left Join
    #tab_enderecos e On u.id_usuario = e.id_usuario  
    Left Join #tab_contatos c On u.id_usuario = c.id_usuario 
    ) a 
    WHERE e_cnt =1 AND c_cnt =1

Comment: ai para funcionar voce tem que criar um row number para o contato tbm.

Comment: haha, alguem deu um -1 de novo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode agrupar pelo `id_usuario`:

```
Select
    u.id_usuario,
    u.usuario,
    u.nome,
    e.id_endereco,
    e.cidade,
    e.uf
From
    tab_usuarios u Left Join
    tab_enderecos e On u.id_usuario = e.id_usuario

/* aqui */
GROUP BY 
    id_usuario
```

[Veja aqui no sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0b65a/2/0)

Se você precisar pegar o maior id no agrupamento pode usar o `max()`:

```
Select
    u.id_usuario,
    u.usuario,
    u.nome,
    e.id_endereco,
    e.cidade,
    e.uf
From
    tab_usuarios u 
    Left Join tab_enderecos e On u.id_usuario = e.id_usuario
WHERE e.id_endereco IN (
  SELECT MAX(id_endereco)
     FROM tab_enderecos
     WHERE id_usuario = u.id_usuario
)
```

[Veja aqui no sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b83737/8)

Comment: cara, na real, não funcionou. eles trás pra mim o max do id_endereco, mas os outros campos da tabela endereço, como cidade e UF, não trás de acordo com este id

Comment: @FabioGomes hmm  pode cre... viajei

Comment: @FabioGomes alterado mano

Answer (score -2):

Pode usar o SELECT DISTINCT

Link para visualização do material W3S
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Opa, com distinct o resultado é o mesmo

Answer (score -2):

Query Resposta

```
Select
    u.id_usuario,
    u.usuario,
    u.nome,
    e.id_endereco,
    e.endereco
From
    tab_usuarios u 
Left Join
    tab_endereco e On u.id_usuario = e.id_usuario
Group by
  u.id_usuario,
  e.id_usuario
```

Exemplo

```
CREATE TABLE `tab_usuarios` (
  `id_usuario` INT NOT NULL,
  `usuario` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_endereco` INT NOT NULL,
  `cidade` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `uf` VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE `tab_endereco` (
`id_endereco` INT NOT NULL,  
`id_usuario` INT NOT NULL,
  `endereco` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);
  
INSERT INTO tab_usuarios
VALUES 
('1','admin'          , 'Administrador', 2, 'cidade', 'SP'),
('2','user 2'         , 'user 2'       , 22, 'Lorena', 'SP'),
('2','user 2'         , 'user 2'       , 20, 'Lorena', 'SP'),
('3','jao'            , 'Joao Silva'   , 24, 'Campinas', 'SP'),
('4','teste'          , 'fabio'        , 28, 'Lorena', 'SP');

INSERT INTO tab_endereco
VALUES 
('1','1','Rua Stack');
INSERT INTO tab_endereco
VALUES 
('2','1','Rua Stack 2');
```